# Function getopt in C with char*const* pointer

Tags: c, getopt

I would like to make a third argument possible, as shown here:
(filename at any position like this)

```
program -a 3 <filename> -b 6
program -a 3 -b 6 <filename>
```

How can I do this with `getopt` and save this string in the variable `file`?

```
int main(int argc, char *const *argv) {

   int a = 0;   int b = 0; int i = 0;  
   char *A;     char *B;
   char *file = NULL;

   int c;opterr = 0; 
  
   while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1)  {
     switch (c) {

       case 'a': a = 1; A = optarg; break;
       case 'b': b = 1; B = optarg; break;

       case '?': 
         if (optopt == 'c')             fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.", optopt);
         else if (isprint (optopt))     fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.", optopt);
         else                           fprintf (stderr,"Unknown option character `\\x%x'.",optopt);

       default: file = optarg; break; }}

   
   strcpy(&file,*(argv + i));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `file` is a pointer, then `&file` is a pointer to a pointer (of type `char **`). Which is not what `strcpy` expect. You need to pass a pointer to the first element of an already allocate array. There are plenty of documentation about `strcpy` all over. Including in every decent text book, which you should read.

Comment: Note the the GNU version of [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) supports what you want unless you set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment or starting the option string with a `+` sign.  However, the version of [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) standardized by POSIX does not do such permutation of the arguments (or recognize the option string starting with a plus sign as special).  The C standard is silent on `getopt()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getopt` function expects all arguments to be before all non-arguments.  So processing `program -a 3 <filename> -b 6` is not possible with `getopt`.  Either the filename has to be at the end or there has to be an option letter associated with it.

Regarding reading the filename, you would do it after the getopt loop.  The `optind` variable contains the index of the next argument not yet processed, so can subtract this value from `argc` and add it to `argv` to process the remaining arguments starting from 0.

```
argc -= optind;
argv += optind;
file = argv[0];
```